# Azure DevOps - Azure App Service deploy - Adds Application settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE causes CSS to not load

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-pipelines

In Azure DevOps we have the following Azure App Service deploy task in our release pipeline:

[image]

This works good but it adds `Application settings` `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1` for Azure App Service

[image]

The web application starts but for some reason `/lib/ionic/release/css/ionic.min.css` is not loaded with this setting.

[image]

If I remove `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` and upload the exact same files via FTP everything works as expected.

[image]

I know `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` comes from the .zip file deployment but is there anyway to modify the task to simply upload a folder or do I need to use the `FTP upload` task then? I know `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` makes wwwroot read-only but what could be causing this? With this setting a GET to the resource simple gives the following error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the upload with `FTP Upload task`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops

[image]

However after doing this I still had the same error.

Went into App Service Console and there I could not see the file at all.

[image]

I finally solved it by looking at the file name, `/lib/ionic/release/css/ionic.min.css`. In our `.gitignore` file we exclude  `[Rr]elease/`. Adding a ignore with `!AppFolder/**` solved it so the files were added to git.