# How to deploy Functions in Azure Pipelines for WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

Microsoft's [Run your functions from a package file in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package) recommends running functions with `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1`. In '*Using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1*' section one can read:

> - Zip deployment is the recommended way to upload a deployment package to your site.

In [Continuous delivery with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Ccsharp) we can read in '*Deploy your app*' section for Classic deployments (as opposed to YAML deployments) that:

> You'll need to create a separate release pipeline to deploy to Azure Functions. When you create a new release pipeline, search for the Azure Functions release template.

In the *Azure Functions* task one must choose the *Deployment method* and the options are:

- Auto-detect
- Zip Deploy
- Run From Package

[image]

I am confused by

- an option called *Run From Package* next to *Zip Deploy* option and
- the documentation saying

  > Zip deployment is the recommended way to upload a deployment package to your site

How to correctly deploy a function using Pipelines' *Azure Functions* task?

Comment: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102990/azure-devops-azure-app-service-deploy-adds-application-settings-website-run)

Comment: @RithwikBojja-MT Interestingly for me Pipelines do not add  WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1 (but when deploying locally with VS Code + A Functions extension the setting is added). I was considering adding a paragraph about this but I didn't want to have multiple issues in one question.

Comment: @RithwikBojja-MT Your "Reference about the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" is the first like I have in the post :/